# are Careers 2.0 active on Google Code invites coming?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

[image] Where is google code? When it will come to SO Careers 2.0?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use GitHub and CodePlex because you can authorize us to look at the data for your account on those sites (your repos etc).  The authorization lets us know that the account actually belongs to you.

When Google Code allows us to do that it'll become a candidate for granting invites immediately.

Comment: *STATUS-PUNYONED*

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: How many times do I have to tell you it's PUNYOWNED

Comment: What does `PUNYOWNED` or `PUNYONED` mean? Is process of making this feature happen running? Do negotiations with google take any place on SO C2.0 or google has literally rejected SO?

Comment: And BTW what about ohloh profiles (thay agregate lots of svn's gits etc and keep indexing tham)...?

Comment: @Kabumbus:  Jeff likes to use my last name as a verb sometimes...As for ohloh, could you ask that in a separate question?  Thanks

Comment: @Jason Punyon: Added question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106260/are-careers-2-0-ohloh-profiles-integration-coming).