# are Careers 2.0 Ohloh profiles integration coming?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

[image]

Where is an option for [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/) profile which already unites many OSS projects and monitors them? When it will come to SO Careers 2.0 invites form?

Also I wonder if it would come to Careers 2.0 how it would cooperate with SO Careers 2.0 Open Source tab... (because Ohloh as SO Careers monitors projects from different hosts, and it already knows technologies I (or at least project manager) like to mention, revision history etc...)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any current plans to support Ohloh since it's not really a primary source but another aggregator.  But if enough people want to see it and vote up this request we'll take another look.